# Mapper not producing records when using FloatWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to write a simple mapper that reads a csv file and emits one column as key and another as value, discarding everything else. Both columns have numeric data. The mapper works when I treat both key and value as text. However, when I try to return the value as float, it does not return any rows.

Heres my code (commented code that treats value as Text and worked):

```
public static class FiltrationMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, FloatWritable>{


    private Text keyText = new  Text();
    //private Text valText = new  Text();   

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        String line = value.toString();   
        String[] parts = line.split(",");

        try
        {
            int pickupLocationId = Integer.parseInt(parts[0].trim());            
            float fare = Float.parseFloat(parts[3].trim());            

            if(pickupLocationId >= 0 && distance > 0 && fare > 0)
            {
                String keyStr = Integer.toString(pickupLocationId);
                keyText.set(keyStr);

                //private Text valText = new  Text();   
                //String valStr = Float.toString(fare);
                //valText.set(valStr);
                FloatWritable f = new FloatWritable(fare);


                context.write(keyText, f);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }

    }
  }
```

Comment: By the way, this is maybe 3 lines of code in Spark or Pig... What happens when you actually put a some logging in catch block? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Try putting `e.printStackTrace` in the exception block. It might tell us something.